# Camunda set Assignee to Owner

Tags: owner, camunda

I'm modeling a process at a given time and want to assign a User Task to the user who created the instance of the process.

What should I put in my User Task "Assignee" field?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

We solve this by setting a "startedBy" process variable on process start. Then, just use the variable value in the Assignee field: ${startedBy}.

You will have to modify your process start to get the logged in user. This can either be done by passing the variable to the "startProcessByKey" ... method or implementing a Listener on the start event that tries to get the user from the current session.

Comment: Ty ! I can do this in my @ProcessApplication class ? Overwriting with one method ?

Comment: Do you have a custom tasklist or application that starts the process instances or do you use the camunda default?

Comment: I'm using the project as described in this URL http://camunda.org/get-started/developing-process-applications.html. You indicate me use another type of project?

Answer (score 0):

end listener on the start event works fine:

```
<camunda:executionListener expression="${execution.setVariable(&#39;startedBy&#39;, authenticatedUserId)}" event="end" />
```

Answer (score 0):

We can set the process initiator through IdentityService.

```
public void test(){
    //start process
    identityService.setAuthenticatedUserId(userId);
    ProcessInstance processInstance = runtimeService.startProcessInstanceById(processDefinitionId);
    //query
    historyService.createHistoricProcessInstanceQuery().startedBy(userId).list()
}
```